# How to stop Appium server programmatically and automated in Jenkins Pipeline

Tags: jenkins, automated-tests, jenkins-pipeline, appium, jenkins-groovy

Appium server sometimes it does not stop when you try to close it, server and port is still hanging forever and the Appium CLI has no build-in command to stop the server which makes it harder to manage programmatically

Imagine that you want to manage it programmatically with the automation process in your CI/CD pipeline 
such as Jenkins it could be a really painful story

```sh
appium
or
appium & (as background process)
```

*The command to start Appium server that can be stopped only when you terminate it but sometimes it not stop*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've searched for the answer on StackOverflow for a long time and none of them answer directly to my question

So far what seems to work is that you have to kill the process of the server manually in the shell with the specific process id

To make it simply work with the pipeline, we could have a short version of the command

```sh
 kill $(lsof -t -i :4723)
 kill \$(lsof -t -i :${APPIUM_PORT}) [In Jenkinsfile]
```

Where the **APPIUM_PORT** is your Appium port, the default port is **4723**
**lsof** command should work in Unix-like systems e.g. MacOS, Linux

> lsof is a command meaning "list open files", which is used in many
>   Unix-like systems to report a list of all open files and the processes
>   that opened them

By running this command it should return an ID of the process running on that specific port to use for the kill signal

To implement in the pipeline
Add this step at the end of your Jenkinsfile

```
    post{
        always{
            ...
            echo "Stop appium server"
            sh "kill \$(lsof -t -i :${APPIUM_PORT})"
        }
        success{
            ...
        }
        failure{
            ...
        }
        cleanup{
            ...
        }
    }
```

It should kill the hanging Appium server process and you can start the new Appium server again with the same port!

To see more details on this I already publish a blog here
[How to start/stop Appium server in Jenkins Pipeline](https://medium.com/@gurojiratchaya/how-to-start-stop-appium-server-in-jenkins-pipeline-5b346bc31942)

Hope it helps